# What happen to my validation in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem validatin fields in my code usign cakephp3.4.13

It always says "This field cannot be left empty" event the username fields has value input, but when i remove the validation in userstable.php it will submit but the username field is empty in the database.

PLease help me

Userstable.php

```
 public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {

$validator
    ->integer('id')
    ->allowEmpty('id', 'create'); 

   $validator->requirePresence('username', 'Please enter username.');
$validator
    ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('password', 'You must enter a password', 'create')
        ->add('password', [
            'length' => [
            'rule' => ['minLength', 8],
            'message' => 'Passwords must be at least 8 characters long.',
        ]
    ]);
$validator
    ->requirePresence('age', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('age');
$validator
    ->requirePresence('address', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('address');
$validator
    ->email('email')
    ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('email');
$validator
    ->requirePresence('gender', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('gender');
return $validator;
    }


public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
        return $rules;
    }

Userscontroller.php //register

<?php

public function register()
{

        $user= $this->Users->newEntity();

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {      

            $image_name        = $this->request->data['profile_pic']['name'];
            $image_tmp         = $this->request->data['profile_pic']['tmp_name'];

            $destination       = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$image_name;


            move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$destination);
            $this->request->data['profile_pic'] = $image_name;
            $this->request->data['destination'] = $destination;


            $user= $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {

            $this->Flash->success(__('Data has been saved.'));


            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {

            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);

    }

?>
```

User.php //Model/Entity

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Model\Entity;
    use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
    use Cake\ORM\Entity;

    /**
     * User Entity.
     */
    class User extends Entity
    {

        protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
        ];
        protected function _setPassword($password)
        {
           return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
        }
    }
?>
```

register.ctp

```
<div class="actions columns large-2 medium-3">
    <h3><?= __('Actions') ?></h3>
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="users form large-10 medium-9 columns">
  <div id="output"></div>

  <?php 
    if ($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.username')) {
         echo"You must logout first ";
         print $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.username'); 
         echo $this->Html->link('Logout',array('controller' =>'users','action' => 'logout')); 

    }else{
  ?>
    <?php
      //$this->Form->create($user, array('class' => 'insertForm'));
      echo $this->Form->create($user, array('type'=>'file'));
    ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add User') ?></legend>
        <?php
         $date_posted = date("Y-m-d") ; 


            echo $this->Form->input('username');
             echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('age');
            $options = ['Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female']; 
            echo $this->Form->input('gender', array(
                'options' => $options,
                'type' => 'select',
                //'empty' => 'Select the gender',
                'label' => 'Gender')
            );
            echo $this->Form->input('address');
            echo $this->Form->input('created',array('type'=>'hidden','value' => $date_posted)); 
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
            echo $this->Form->input('profile_pic', ['type' => 'file']);

        ?>
    </fieldset>    
    <?php echo $this->Form->button('Register', ['type' => 'submit']); ?>


    <?php  } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what is in your entity that you are trying to save?

Comment: @AlexStallen is that the entity you are looking that I posted below. in my post

Comment: No I ment the actual entity you are trying to save, the one that holds your data

Comment: You say that the username has input, but the validation says it's empty and when you save it the result is also empty, so it seems pretty likely that the username field is not, in fact, getting data into it.

Comment: @AlexStallen  is the register method in userscontrolle.php you are looking for? I already put, i could not understand something because im new to CAKEPHP, Please help me

Comment: @GregSchmidt yes I input value on the username field form but error always occur, thats why i remove the validation in userstable.php, then it will save but still the username will not save in db

Comment: What we want to see is the data in the entity that you're trying to save. The results of `debug($user);` after the patch, in other words. You may be filling in the field labelled Username, but the data isn't getting into the entity, for example.

Comment: @GregSchmidt  is this one? i debug the user when submiting register button  https://ibb.co/h8MdXb

Comment: Yes, that is the one. You can see that there is no 'username' field present in the entity that you are trying to safe. that is the reason you get a validation error, or when removing the validation that the field 'username' is being saved as empty. Make sure your username field is being filled, is it on the form, does it have the correct name, do you alter the data before the safe in any way (maybe you remove it) etc etc?

Comment: I also updated the version of my cakephp to 3.5 but their is an error upon upgrade then I SWITCH to cakephp3.4.13

Comment: @AlexStallen ACTUALLY I dont know what the reason for this, this only occur when i added, address,gender and age fields in the table, I ALWAYS filled the username field in the form upon hitting register button

Comment: Let's see the result of debugging `$this->request->data` now. And maybe the input form implementation.

Comment: @GregSchmidt here is  the data  https://ibb.co/e3FaTG

Comment: I also added the register.ctp form in the questions

Comment: The username field in that data is indeed blank. You said you always fill it in? Maybe search everywhere in your code for username and see if something else is intercepting the data and messing with it before it even gets to this function.

Comment: What other files may affect this scenario @GregSchmidt,  I could not locate anything, Im always looking in Userscontroller/register method, Userstable.php, register.ctp

Comment: Theoretically, it could be just about anywhere. Most likely, do you have a beforeMarshal or beforeRules function defined in either your UsersTable or the class that it extends? Or a behavior attached to either of those classes? Or are there any generic or specific event handlers anywhere for those events that might be getting fired?

Comment: The other files I touch was AppController.php but I comment the code  and it does not affect the register method